# Google Play : Multiple builds under review in the same track

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

We can see that in the Open Testing track, we have more then 1 builds under review. How is that possible. I have always seen that as soon as we uploaded a new build for review, earlier build under review will get super seeded.

Any idea?

-Ajay